# How do i store all the values of a constantly changing variable?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, realm

I am using a recyclerview with cardview in it to display my data. Each card has an ImageView which, when clicked, sends the data in that card to favorites. I am using a static variable to get the data of the card of which ImageView is clicked. I then send the data of that static variable to my Favorites database. My problem is that if I click the favroties imageview of two or more cards, only the data of the last card is saved in favorites. This is because the value of my static variable gets updated each time I click an imageview. How can I get multiple values instead of just the value of the last imageview I click?

`public void onBindViewHolder(final SubCategoryHolder holder, final int position) {

```
    SubCategories s = subCategories.get(position);
    holder.subCategoryText.setText(s.getName());
    holder.subCategoryIdText.setText(s.getId());
    holder.likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_before_like);
    setFadeAnimation(holder.itemView);

    //handling like button
    holder.likeImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int id = (int) holder.likeImageView.getTag();
            if(id == R.drawable.ic_before_like){
                holder.likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_favorites);
                holder.likeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorites);
                favoritesName = holder.subCategoryText.getText().toString();  // favoritesName is static
                favoritesId = holder.subCategoryIdText.getText().toString();  //favoritesId is static

            }else{
                holder.likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_before_like);
                holder.likeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_before_like);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

`

```
    //getting favorites data
    String favoritesName = SubCategoryAdapter.favoritesName; //assigning static value to favoritedsName here
    String favoritesId = SubCategoryAdapter.favoritesId; //assigning static value to favoritesId here

    //assigning the favorites data to Favorites database
    Favorites f = new Favorites();
    f.setFavoritesNames(favoritesName);
    f.setFavoritesId(favoritesId);



    //saving the assigned data
    if(favoritesName != null)
    {
        if(helper.save(f))
        {
            SubCategoryAdapter.favoritesName = null;
            SubCategoryAdapter.favoritesId = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use an ArrayList<Favorites> of type favorites. And when one clicks on the fav button add that fav object to arraylist. This way all the images that were clicked as favs will be saved in the arraylist.
But remember to check if the image is already clicked otherwise you will end up saving multiple favorites of same id.

Comment: How is this question Realm-related? All I see here is using static variables where one should not use static variables. If there is Realm involved, this current code is even *worse*.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have used realm to store favorites. My original idea was to add a boolean in the categories and when I add a card to favorites the boolean becomes true and I'll only show the data with boolean as true in favorites section. I am using Initialrealm to store intial categories data. How do I change the boolean value of initial data and make those changes persist when reloading the acitivity? I know the above code is bad and I don't want to use the static variable. Can you tell me how can I change the boolean value of already stored realm data and make it persist on reloading?

Comment: By writing the change into the Realm in a transaction, and displaying managed RealmObjects directly from managed RealmResults obtained from Realm that you listen to with RealmChangeListener to keep in sync (although for adapters, the RealmChangeListener step can be replaced with using `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` which does the same thing)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I can't find any proper documentation for RealmRecyclerViewAdapter. I am still searching.

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#adapters

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks a lot! I was able to solve the issue without using any static variables.